# Excel Formula to generate separate list table

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a list of names taken from a column which contains duplicate names within it.
I want to create a separate table (so not effecting the data itself) which displays the most common values down to the most unique.
For example:

```
David
Peter
Paul
Albert
Jules
Hector
David
Albert
Hector
Hector
David
David
```

This would then display in a separate table/sheet as:

```
David
Hector
Albert
Paul
Peter
Jules
```

Any help you can give would be invaluable.

Kind Regards
Thomas

Comment: You just want to get the unique values from a column?

Comment: Sorry it didnt copy in my question very well.
I want the unique values to appear in a separate column, so not altering the original list. But the new column will be in order of values that appeared most to least.
So in the example the top entry will be David as it appears 4 times in the original column, but this will only appear once in the new column. Then second value in the column would be Hector, as he appears 3 times etc etc

Comment: nightcrawler23 has given a good suggestion, although you could just use a pivot table to calculate all this easily, unless you're opposed to that.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your data to another column and use remove duplicates to get unique names. then use `COUNTIF` formula to get number of occurrences in the main data. Then sort this table

```
=COUNTIF($O$2:$O$26,Q2)
```

[image: Sort by Count]

Answer (score 1):

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$100;MATCH(0;COUNTIF(C1;$A$1:$A&100);0));"")}
```

`$A$1:$A&100` is the range where you want to check the names

The `C1` argument should be the cell above the one that you are going to use the formula on. So this formula can be applied on the cell `C2` with the name's list on the `A:A` column.

This function will create the list of unique values.  Remember to press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> when you put the formula on the first cell, then scroll down.

Then check how many repetitions they got, with the `COUNTIF` formula. Copy the unique values to an empty sheet to avoid errors.  Sort the values in ascending way and extend the selection, you will get the result you want.

Even though I think the easiest option would be to create a pivot table.

Comment: For whatever reason, pivot tables seem to be heavily under-utilized in Excel